# Advanced averaging with multiindex dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In this multiindexed dataframe,

```
               c1        c2        c3
major minor                              
a     1     -1.202766 -0.502679  1.915304
      2      0.097658  0.604051 -0.497243
      3     -1.285027 -1.200143  0.087209
d     3     -0.231444  1.518543  2.139600
      4     -1.336436 -0.299769 -0.600134
      5     -0.873389  1.949733 -0.757263
a     1     -0.222766 -2.302679  0.615304
      2      1.047648  1.304051 -1.497243
      3     -1.285027 -1.000143  0.087209
d     3     -0.631464  1.318543  0.139600
      4     -0.316436 -0.193749 -1.500134
      5     -0.693689  0.449753 -1.347263
```

I'd like to get the average on the repeated major indices, that is, sth like this

```
            c1        c2        c3
major minor                              
a     1     -1.202766 -0.502679  1.915304
      2      0.097658  0.604051 -0.497243
      3     -1.285027 -1.200143  0.087209
d     3     -0.231444  1.518543  2.139600
      4     -1.336436 -0.299769 -0.600134
      5     -0.873389  1.949733 -0.757263
```

where the values are the average values. Obviously `df.groupby(level='major').mean()` doesn't work here, since the minor indexes are also averaged to one value. How to proceed?

Comment: `df.groupby(level=['major', 'minor']).mean().dropna()`

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved me a lot of time on this.

Comment: I also found out that `df.mean(level=['major','minor'])` does the job too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `df.groupby(level=['major', 'minor']).mean().dropna()` will create mean values conditional on both axis.

**Follow up on the discussion in the comments**

For your bad data structure case with non unique column names, the following hack works:

```
LL = [pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(df[i]).mean(axis=1), columns=[i]) for i in df.columns.unique()]
pd.concat(LL, axis=1)
```

`pd.DataFrame(df[i])` ensures that `df[i]` is a `DataFrame`, in case the column name is not a duplicat. The rest is just about collecting the dataframes and then stacking them.

**A better data structure**

Say you have different data sets collected:

```
 id c1 c2 c1 c2
  0  1  1  2  2
  1  3  4  5  6
```

a better way to save this is to have a sample identifier

```
 sample id c1 c2 
      0  0  1  1 
      1  0  2  2 
      0  1  3  4  
      1  1  5  6
```

Now, you have your properly identified multi layer data, where you can create the mean values over the different samples.

Comment: A side question. How would you take the average on repeated column values (let's say c1 is repeated twice for instance)?

Comment: For example, if `result` already contains your mean values for the columns `c11` and `c12`, you could do `result[['c11', 'c12']].mean(axis=1)` which applies `mean()` on a horizontal level. By selecting the proper columns, we ensure this will only be applied to the two relevant columns.

Comment: Yes but I have 30 columns. 10 of them are unique and the others have  repeated names as the first 10. I just need the columns with the same names to be averaged. Like: c1,c1,c1,c2,c2,c2,c3,c3,c3 ---> c1,c2,c3

Comment: I'll think about this, but I know nothing off the top of my head. I'll leave the remark that this bad data structure.

Comment: Ironically it's possible if you have a multiindex. Let's say I set an upper level called 'colgroup' that contains all those columns. Then you can factually do `df.mean(axis=1, level=['colgroup','colname'])` and it works. But if you have only a simple index with the aforementioned cols then i found no way to do it.

Comment: Yes, because a MultiIndex is the (one) proper way of storing multi layer data. Having several columns with the same name is not. Anyhow, I added a hacky workaround to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! But why is it a bad way? Having multiple repeated columns of data is a very common way raw data is collected before averaging for error minimizing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58004/discussion-between-foobar-and-gmask).